# *ngIf directive in Angular does not refresh the template when the condition is not met

Tags: angular-ng-if

I have an angular mat-table where I show a calendar with data and I want to show all the days of the month or only one of the 2 fortnights, so I have one variables to set the type of vision of my calendar (vistaCalendario) and another one to set the fortnight (quincenaurl).

The type of vision is selected from these icons

[image]

But this condition is no respected

[image]

the column M1 should only be shown when vista Calendario is "mes" or "quincena" but quincena en la Url is 1 and here that condition is not met and even so it is shown

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use switchabe div

```
<div *ngIf="vistaCalendario == 'mes'; else elseTemplate" >
      --Your code----
</div>

<div #elseTemplate *ngIf="vistaCalendario == 'quincena' && quincenaurl == 1" >
    ----Your code----
</div>
```